# Producing a "triangle of caret symbols" With data validation in java

Tags: java, validation, output

I have to make a program that produces a triangle of caret symbols when the user enter a whole number. I got how to make the triangle but I don't know how to get it to follow the data validation.

[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xh4W.png)

```
public class program7 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int space=29;
    char ch;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        ch = '^';  

        //Print spaces in decreasing order. A is at 29th position.
        for (int j = 1; j <= space; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        //Print Triangle.
        for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++) {
            System.out.print(ch + " ");
            ch+=1;
        }

        space--;

        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Also how can I make it so that ^ is in the tangle and nothing else?

Comment: "Follow the data validation" ???????

Comment: You should probably step back and first clarify your requirements... Then you take a piece of paper and "ran" algorithms manually to understand what is required to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I wont fully answer your question but regarding your validation of input it seems you are only expected to deal with integer input therefore you could use a [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) like below:

***Note:*** I have left out the the code for `printRightTriangleLHS` as an exercise for you. It is the easiest one :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class program7 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = 0;

    while((number < 3) || (number > 10)) {
      System.out.print("Please enter a number between 3 and 10: ");
      number = scanner.nextInt();
    }

    printSpacing(1);
    printRightTriangleLHS(number);
    printRightTriangleRHS(number);
    printEquliateralTriangle(number);
    System.out.println("Process Completed!");
  }

  public static void printRightTriangleLHS(int height) {
    System.out.println("Right Triangle with angle on LHS");
    printSpacing(2);
  }

  public static void printRightTriangleRHS(int height) {
    System.out.println("Right Triangle with angle on RHS");
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        System.out.print(" ");
      for (int j = i; j < height; j++)
        System.out.print("^");
      System.out.println();
    }
    printSpacing(2);
  }

  public static void printEquliateralTriangle(int height) {
    System.out.println("Equliateral Triangle");
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < height - i; j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
      }
      for(int k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
        System.out.print("^ ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
    printSpacing(2);
  }

  public static void printSpacing(int lineBreaks) {
    for(int i = 1; i <= lineBreaks; i++) {
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/GfZE/1)

**Current Example Usage:**

```
Please enter a number between 3 and 10:  55
Please enter a number between 3 and 10:  -11
Please enter a number between 3 and 10:  0
Please enter a number between 3 and 10:  5

Right Triangle with angle on LHS


Right Triangle with angle on RHS
^^^^^
 ^^^^
  ^^^
   ^^
    ^


Equliateral Triangle
     ^ 
    ^ ^ 
   ^ ^ ^ 
  ^ ^ ^ ^ 
 ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ 


Process Completed!
```